# Remove the Permission denied error when copying with ADB

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

My device is an Android Studio Virtual Device (AVD).

I have rooted it with rootAVD (https://github.com/newbit1/rootAVD).

I want to transfer the system folder from the Android root to my operating system (Macintosh).

**I run the following command in the terminal:**

```
adb pull system Downloads/Root
```

**But I get the following errors when running:**

```
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/acpi: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/base64: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/basename: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/blockdev: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/cal: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/cat: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/chcon: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/chgrp: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/chmod: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/chown: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/chroot: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/chrt: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/cksum: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/clear: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/cmp: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/comm: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/cp: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/cpio: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/cut: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/date: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/dd: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/df: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/diff: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/dirname: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/dmesg: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/dos2unix: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/du: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/echo: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/env: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/expand: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/expr: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/fallocate: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/false: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/file: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/find: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/flock: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/free: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/getenforce: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/getevent: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/getprop: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/groups: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/gunzip: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/gzip: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/head: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/hostname: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/hwclock: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/id: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/ifconfig: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/inotifyd: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/insmod: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/ionice: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/iorenice: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/kill: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/killall: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/ln: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/load_policy: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/log: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/logname: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/losetup: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/ls: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/lsmod: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/lsof: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/lspci: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/lsusb: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/md5sum: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/microcom: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/mkdir: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/mkfifo: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/mknod: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/mkswap: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/mktemp: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/modinfo: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/modprobe: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/more: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/mount: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/mountpoint: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/mv: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/netstat: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/newfs_msdos: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/nice: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/nl: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/nohup: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/od: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/paste: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/patch: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/pgrep: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/pidof: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/pkill: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/pmap: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/printenv: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/printf: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/ps: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/pwd: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/readlink: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/realpath: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/renice: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/restorecon: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/rm: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/rmdir: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/rmmod: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/runcon: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/sed: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/sendevent: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/seq: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/setenforce: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/setprop: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/setsid: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/sha1sum: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/sha224sum: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/sha256sum: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/sha384sum: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/sha512sum: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/sleep: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/sort: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/split: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/start: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/stat: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/stop: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/strings: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/swapoff: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/swapon: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/sync: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/sysctl: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/tac: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/tail: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/tar: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/taskset: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/tee: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/time: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/timeout: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/top: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/touch: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/tr: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/true: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/truncate: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/tty: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/ulimit: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/umount: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/uname: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/uniq: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/unix2dos: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/uptime: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/usleep: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/uudecode: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/uuencode: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/vmstat: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/wc: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/which: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/whoami: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/xargs: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/xxd: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/yes: Permission denied
adb: warning: stat failed for path system/bin/zcat: Permission denied
adb: error: failed to copy 'system/build.prop' to 'Downloads/Root/system/build.prop': remote open failed: Permission denied
```

I checked other answers on stackoverflow none of them worked for me!

How can I get rid of the **Permission denied** error completely?

Comment: just curious, what are you planning to do with the downloaded files?

Comment: Editing the build.prop file and checking the rest of the files

Answer (score 0):

Run adb as root first and then copy the files after:

`adb root`

Comment: abd root also gives this error "adbd cannot run as root in production builds"

Answer (score 0):

You have *not* rooted it.
Ref: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/modules/adb/+/HEAD/daemon/restart_service.cpp#37
To see whether you do indeed have root rights, see whether you can run `adb root` on your terminal window.
PS: On an android device that is rooted, `adb root` might still require to also followup with `adb remount` + `adb reboot` before you can run `adb root`